# Proportional barplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a proportional barplot in R, so far I have managed to do something like this:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=diamonds)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=cut,y=..prop..,fill=color))
```

This obviously does not work, but neither does this:

```
ggplot(data=diamonds)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=cut,y=..prop..,fill=color,group=1))
```

or this:

```
ggplot(data=diamonds)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=cut,y=..count../sum(..count..),fill=color))
```

This works:

```
ggplot(data=diamonds)+
  geom_bar(aes(x=cut,y=..count../sum(..count..),fill=color),position="fill")
```

But I would like bars to be side by side within a category.

What I want to do is to get proportional barplot without transforming my data before

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to aggregate first and then use `position="dodge"`:

```
diamonds2 <- aggregate(carat ~ cut + color, diamonds, length)

ggplot(data = transform(diamonds2, p = ave(carat, cut, FUN = function(x) x/sum(x))), 
       aes(x = cut, y = p, fill=color))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: it is not correct within a category proportions will not sum to one

Comment: Is it possible to do that without doing aggregation first ?

Comment: the plot which you show is exactly the one I want but I do not want to aggregate before

Comment: @Vitalijs I'm afraid that's not possible

Answer (score 0):

EDIT after OP's comment

If you want conditional and side-by-side histograms use `geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")` when you call your conditional histogram plot with `ggplot2` (I display the first 100 rows of data for sake of clarity)

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = diamonds[1:100, ], aes(cut, carat, fill = color)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Comment: it is not proportional i.e. I want colors to sum to 1 within each category, and I want bars side by side

Comment: I see; the proportionality can be achieved by dividing by `sum(count)` and side by side is another condition in `geom_bar`, i.e. `position = "dodge"`

Comment: Where should I divide by sum count ?

Comment: Please see @h3rm4n answer: you need to specify the normalization  `y=..count../sum(..count..)` for your histograms

Comment: if I add this to geom_bar I get an error, your chart is still not proportional